# Formatting namenode on Hadoop - windows 7

Tags: windows, hadoop, format

I am trying to install Hadoop on windows 7 with Cygwin. I have installed Cygwin and can login ssh localhost without password.

I have changed the hadoop-env.sh  as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME=C:\\Progra~1\\Java\\jre7
```

and in my system variables, I have `JAVA_HOME` set to:

```
C:\Progra~1\Java\jre7
```

and `PATH` set to:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\cygwin\bin;C:\cygwin\usr\sbin
```

When I type `C:>echo %JAVA_HOME%`  getting the result as:

`C:\Progra~1\Java\jre7`

when I run

```
$ bin/hadoop version
```

I get the following:

```
/bin/java: No such file or directoryva\jre7

/bin/java: No such file or directoryva\jre7

/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

and when I run

```
$ bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

I get the same thing:

```
/bin/java: No such file or directoryva\jre7

/bin/java: No such file or directoryva\jre7

/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

I know that this question might be easy to solve for expert people, but I am new to hadoop and I have looked everywhere for a solution to this issue. Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Quit Cygwin.

Install a JDK (not a JRE) properly in a Path with no blanks. For example : `C:\jdk1.7.0_21`

Add an environnement variable JAVA_HOME to `C:\jdk1.7.0_21`

Add the JAVA_HOME/bin to your PATH.

Edit hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh : Uncomment the JAVA_HOME Export. For my example :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/jdk1.7.0_21/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will try it and get back to you.

Comment: I've made a lot of tests, and it is difficult to find a version of Hadoop willing to start with Cygwin. The 0.20.2 works greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Use double comma if your path contains space.

export JAVA_HOME="/cygdrive/C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45"